# modalPresentationStyle from button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a _exampleButton:

```
_exampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_exampleButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [_exampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(certificatesButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_exampleButton];
```

and the action:

```
    -(void)certificatesButtonTouched
{
    if(!_certificatesWindow)
    {
        _certificatesWindow = [[AWCertificatesViewController alloc] init];


        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                 initWithRootViewController:_certificatesWindow];
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [_certificatesWindow release];

    }
    else {

        [_certificatesWindow.view removeFromSuperview];
        [_certificatesWindow release];
        _certificatesWindow = nil;

        }
    }
```

this presents the window in modal view controller from other class:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(cancel:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelItem;


    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    _tableFromButton = table;
}

- (void)cancel:(id)sender
{

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                      completion:nil];
}
```

but after clicking the Cancel button, the Modal view controller view disappears, but if I click the _exampleButton again once- it will not appear, so I have to click it twice to show the modal view controller again. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does this because that is what your code tell it to do...

You dismiss the view controller in `-(void)cancel:(id)sender` but this will not result in the `_certificatesWindow` iVar becoming nil in your first view controller.  So when you touch the `exampleButton` again it will execute the else clause and clean up the `_certificatesWindow` view controller.

You should either use delegation or a code block to have the first view controller dismiss the second or remove the if/else test from your `certificatesButtonTouched`.  Another alternative is to modify this method so that if `_certificatesWindow` is not nil it is reused -

```
   -(void)certificatesButtonTouched
    {
      if(!_certificatesWindow)
      {
         _certificatesWindow = [[AWCertificatesViewController alloc] init];
      }

         UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                 initWithRootViewController:_certificatesWindow];
         navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
         [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

But this may or may not be desirable depending on what the second view controller shows.

I would also suggest you look at converting to ARC if possible

Comment: How to dismiss the view controller in -(void)cancel:(id)sender ?

Comment: You are already doing this in the code in your question with dismissViewController

Comment: I mean how I should use delegation or a code block to have the first view controller dismiss the second?

Comment: Delegation is a commonly used pattern in Objective-C/iOS programming https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html. Blocks is a newer technique that allows you to store a block of code in a variable. You can then store this in a property of your second view controller and call it when necessary https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is after you tap "Cancel", `_certificatesWindow` still exists when you tap on `certificatesButtonTouched`. It will go to the **Else** statement on the **First tap** to make `_certificatesWindow = nil`.

if `_certificatesWindow` is not needed when you tap cancel, you might want to do the following:-

```
- (void)cancel:(id)sender
{

[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:nil];
  [_certificatesWindow.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_certificatesWindow release];
    _certificatesWindow = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

allocate view like this in view did load method

```
 if(!_certificatesWindow)
    {
        _certificatesWindow = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    }

     -(void)certificatesButtonTouched
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:_certificatesWindow];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this

```
    -(void)certificatesButtonTouched
{
    if(!_certificatesWindow)
    {
        _certificatesWindow = [[AWCertificatesViewController alloc] init];
    }

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                   initWithRootViewController:_certificatesWindow];
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [_certificatesWindow release];

    }
```